# Object outside of Promise is empty

Tags: reactjs, promise

I receive the data for the user object by an api call. Inside the getSelectedUser function, the console.log returns the filled user object. But in the console.log in the useEffect returns an empty object. What am I doing wrong?

Foo.tsx

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser>(initialUser);

  useEffect(() => {
    getSelectedUser();
    console.log(user);
  }, []);

  async function getSelectedUser() {
    await getUserById(userId).then((data) => {
      setUser(data);
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Service.tsx

```
export const getUserById = async (userId: string | number) => {
  const user = ...;
  const token = ...;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${apiurl}/${userId}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      ...
    }).then((res) => res.json());
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: if you use await , dont use .then ()
 const response = await fetch(`${apiurl}/${userId}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      ...
    })
const response is your fetched data

Comment: a) it's asynchronous b) `const user` never changes, the update causes your render function to be called again with new values

Comment: Hey @IlyesElayeb, thanks for your comment. This helped too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `state` only has new value when component re-render. So you can put `console.log(user);` out side the useEffect to `check` like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getSelectedUser();
  }, []);
  console.log(user);
```

Or you can use other `useEffect` with dependencies to check the value of new state when compoent re-render

```
useEffect (() => {
  console.log(user);
}, [user])
```